# Cannot use SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sendgrid

I'm trying to use `SendGrid` for send email with my `ASP.NET Core` application, so I configured it in the following way:

Inside the `ConfigureServices` method I added a `Singleton` and a configuration to access to `SendGrid` API:

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, IEmailSender>();
services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

the class `AuthMessageSenderOptions` is part of the software configuration:

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

this class manage the `SendGrid` username and the secret key.

I created a `service` class with implement the `IEmailSender` interface, this is the implementation:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; }

    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("foo@gmail.com", "Foo"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        msg.TrackingSettings = new TrackingSettings
        {
            ClickTracking = new ClickTracking { Enable = false }
        };

        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Then in my `Account` controller (which is used for perform the registration and login), I injected the `IEmailSender` service to the constructor:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

   public AccountController(IEmailSender emailSender)
   {
       _emailSender = emailSender;
   }
```

when I start the application I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender'.'

inside the `Program` class, in particular on this line:

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

this is the full `Program` class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

What I did wrong?

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` so, sorry if I did something stupid, I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) doc to implement the `SendGrid` logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, IEmailSender>();
```

should specify the implementation in the second template argument:

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

Comment: omg, for an "I" I was stuck on this by one hour, thanks Roger, wish you a good day! :)

Comment: This works! You are amazing!